# PixiJS: having two different renderers for antialiasing

Tags: pixi.js

I have a PixiJS canvas rendered with `WebGLRenderer` and I need to find a way to make a decent looking snap of one of my containers with `Graphics` elements in it. Problem is, rendering to texture and `cacheAsBitmap` don't use antialiasing in this render mode.

Is there a way to create a `CanvasRenderer` and use it to render my container into texture? It seems like active `WebGLRenderer` does not allow anything else: there is no error thrown, but rendered texture have only eternal darkness in it. So maybe there is a way to disable it for a moment and then turn it on back again?

There are different other ways to get almost what I want. Using `renderer.generateTexture` with `resolution` set to 2 helps a bit. Finally, I can create really large clone of my container, make some snaps with `generateTexture` and then scale them down. But still it looks a bit odd. And feels like a dirty way to do things too, especially since cloning a container with a lot of content can be a bit problematic in some cases.